# Execute different code of useEffect's callback function on dependency changes

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

A function fetchData() to be called as the component loads and also to be called whenever testA and testB prop to this component changes. And also when only testA prop changes I want to perform state update.
Now the state update is happening when either testA and testB changes.

```
useEffect(()=>{
   fetchData();
   // Only When testA changes I want to update the below state.
   // setTableData([]);
},[testA, testB]);
```

If I use 2 useEffect I will be calling the fetchData twice on initial render. Which is not acceptable.

```
useEffect(()=>{
   fetchData();
   setTableData([]);
},[testA]);

useEffect(()=>{
   fetchData();
},[testB]);
```

How to achieve this functionality using hooks?

Answer (score 0):

You might add a test to one of the hooks before calling `fetchData` to see if you're on the inital render or not. For example, if `fetchData` updates some `data` state, you could have `data` start out undefined and do:

```
useEffect(()=>{
   fetchData();
   setTableData([]);
},[testA]);

useEffect(()=>{
   if (data) {
       // then we're not on the initial render
       fetchData();
   }
},[testB]);
```

Or you could do the same sort of thing with a different stateful variable whose contents can be used to determine if you're on the initial render or not - it doesn't have to be `data`.

Comment: Case 1 : Even If I set the data as 'undefined' initially. It is not guaranteed that 1st useEffect's fetchData() is called and data is set before 2nd useEffect begins. These will get called immediately.

Comment: On mount, both effect callbacks will run at the same time. So the first's `fetchData` will be called, and the second's `fetchData` definitely won't. That's what you want, right?

Comment: So did you try it?